# Are the elements of this set distinct? Can it be considered a set if they are not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm currently reading *Book of Proof* by Richard Hammack. In the chapter on sets, he gives this as an example:

> X = { n<sup>2</sup> : n ∈ **Z** }

If n can be any integer and (-n)<sup>2</sup> = (n)<sup>2</sup>, are the elements of this set distinct? If they are not, is this a set?

To my understanding, sets cannot have repeated elements. However, on the [wikipedia page for sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) it defines a set as

> a collection of **distinct** objects, considered as an object in its own right

but later says

> In an extensional definition, **a set member can be listed two or more times**, for example, {11, 6, 6}.

So can sets have repeated elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it like this: an element $x$ of a set $A$ can be **mentioned** in the notation of the set more than once.

Here $\{11,6,6\}$ is a notation of the unique set that only has the elements $6$ and $11$ (and is completely determined by that fact) and in this notation element $6$ is mentioned twice. That is allowed.

That's all.

Comment: So how would I distinguish a set that mentions an element multiple times and a multiset that contains multiple identical objects that are separate elementst?

Comment: By paying attention to the context that you are working in, I would say. Multisets and sets are distinct mathematical objects. Also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) where is mentioned e.g."...to distinguish between sets and multisets, a notation that incorporates square brackets is sometimes used: the multiset $\{a,a,b\}$ can be denoted as $[a, a, b]$...". I assure you that if you once work with multisets then you will certainly be aware of that too :-). In your question you only mention sets and not multisets.

Comment: One final question. Since {11, 6} and {11, 6, 6} are the same set, do they have the same cardinality?

Comment: Yes, they do. The cardinality is $2$ as you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a set. Note that $\{1,1\}$ and $\{1\}$ are the *same* set. So$$X=\{1,1,4,4,9,9,16,16,\ldots\}=\{1,4,9,16,\ldots\}$$

Comment: Okay, so if I have the set {1,1} and the multiset {1,1}, they are not equal, right?

Comment: I have no experience whatsoever with multisets.

Answer (score 0):

The notation allows to repeat the elements, but as they are identical, they "count once" only. So, strictly,

$$\{11,6,6\}=\{11,6\}.$$

True replication requires a *multiset*.

Comment: How would I know that I am dealing with a set instead of a multiset? Is it supposed to be inferred from  the context?

Comment: @CopelandCorley: of course. Multisets aren't so often met.